# Searching issue with the rails-sunspot gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, search, solr, full-text-search

I'm very new to Solr and the Rails Sunspot gem, but it looks very promising for complex searching on a big database.

What I'm trying to do is allow a model in my rails app to be searched on a few fulltext columns and then a collection of its "filters" (which are just a has_and_belongs_to_many association of names).

I tried setting up my model search block as follows

```
self.searchable do
  text :name, :boost => 5
  text :description, :instructions
  text :filters do
    filters.map(&:name)
  end
end
```

And my controller looks like so:

```
@search = ModelName.search do
  keywords params[:q].to_s
end
```

However, I cannot seem to produce any results based on keywords found in the filters association. Am I doing something wrong? This is all very new to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you initially set up your classes for search, you need to reindex the data into Solr. Have you done that? If not:

```
rake sunspot:reindex
```